# How to send an object as a parameter in radio group

Tags: angular, radio-button, ionic2, ionic2-select

I have an array that i make use of it to dispaly

```
<ion-item (click)="toggleLanguages()">
          Languages
          <ion-icon name="add" item-right *ngIf="languageShow"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="remove" item-right *ngIf="languageHide"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
        <div *ngIf="languageHide">

          <!-- All radio's in a radio group -->

          <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage" (ionChange)="doSomething(language)">
            <ion-item *ngFor="let language of languageArray">
              <ion-label >{{language.language_name}}</ion-label>
              <ion-radio item-left [value]="language"></ion-radio> 
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>

        </div>
```

as you can see i am using `ionchange` to call a funtion

**Problems:**

> when ever my `languageHide` variables become true my `doSomething` funtion is triggering
>
> i am sending `language` object as parameter to my `doSomething(language)` function but in my console log i am getting undefined for language object.

here is my .ts file

```
doSomething(languages){

console.log("invoking dosomething");
console.log("checking languages "+ JSON.stringify(languages));//here it is not printing
}

toggleLanguages(){
  console.log("invoking toggleLanguages");
  this.languageShow = !this.languageShow;
  this.languageHide = !this.languageHide;
}
```

from the above two function i am first invoking toggleLanguages() function
once i invoked this funtion my this.languageHide variable becomes true then my (ionChange) function is triggering automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Ionic, but you should be able to pass `$event`:

```
(ionChange)="doSomething($event)
```

You can then print `$event` in console to see how to extract the data you need:

```
doSomething(event: any){
    console.log(event);
}
```

You can't pass `language` variable because it's not visible in `ion-list` scope, it is defined below.

Comment: thanks but i tried that part if i use $event i am not able to get the language object i am getting the `language.language_name` printed in my console.log but i need the entire language object

Comment: @MohanGopi That doesn't make sense, if you set `[value]="language"`, then you should get whole object. Are you sure you have't changed `value` to `[value]="language.language_name"` in the meantime?

Comment: i am very sure i have not changed it

Comment: @MohanGopi Why don't you simply use `selectedLanguage` variable for getting current value since you used `NgModel` directive to bind selected value to it? You might have to change `[value]` to `[ngValue]` in order for that to work though.

Comment: if i use `[ngValue]`  i am getting error as `ngValue isn't  known property of ion-radio` i have done my code by see this website http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/radio/RadioGroup/

Comment: Thanks i got it worked i found that the problem was because of ngmodel i am updating the value from inital stage once i commented that updation i got the value thanks for the information.

Comment: I have one question because of languageHide become true my ionChange is automaticaly gets triggers how can i stop it